# Little/Big Endian

Tags: java, endianness

How can I determine if the OS is little/big endian in Java?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Java doesn't care and if you're calling native code can't you use that to figure out what architecture you're on?

Comment: Want to do this to know OS details

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981549/javas-virtual-machines-endianness

Comment: @Zed: I think that question is different. It is asking if the VM itself uses big- or little-endian representation internally, not necessarily how to detect what the OS is using.

Answer (score 50):

Check whether [`java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#nativeOrder%28%29) is equal to `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN` or `ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN`.

Comment: @rupa By marking an answer will get you additional 2 points :)

Comment: +1 for having the gumption to ask the OP to "accept" an answer.

Comment: Much like erickson, +1 - both for the correct answer, and the gumption :)