# Java's Virtual Machine's Endianness (suite)

Tags: jvm, endianness

I read this subject ([JVM Endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981549/javas-virtual-machines-endianness)) and I would have a question to the fact that Java is considered as platform independant (which I agree) and by extension does not suffer any problem of endianness (THIS extension has to be taken with care).

Taking advantage of this discussion, here is the next question or scenario : 
- if I try to read with my java application a raw binary file (I know the sequence of structures/types) containing structures previously written by a C program under a Little Endian architecture.

Assuming that my java application is coded in a classic way (Java is "platform independant" so there shouldn't be any problem). Does this case illustrate an endianness problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exchanging binary data, endian-ness must always be part of the specification. If it is not, you have an endianness problem. Unless some software provides guarantees like "serialized objects can be de-serialized on a different machine with a different architecture." 
But in this case, endian problems are addressed in the (de)serialization level.