# Does the result of Integer.toHexString depend on the system endian?

Tags: java, endianness

Is the static method `toHexString()` of `Integer` and `Long` dependent on the system endian, that is does it vary between little endian and big endian platforms?

Does

```
final String hex = Integer.toHexString(123456);
System.out.println(hex);
```

always print `1e240` on **every** supported Java platform?

Comment: Yes. The JVM guarantees it. Anyway, I think it's [Big Endian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981549/javas-virtual-machines-endianness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the representation will always be the same. See [Integer.toHexString(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) and [Java's Virtual Machine's Endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981549/javas-virtual-machines-endianness)

Comment: Thanks. The JavaDoc of `toHexString` doesn't explain the endianess but the second link tells me, that all integer operands with more than one byte are stored in the big endian format.